# How to retrieve some text from a sibling div element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs on a page in this order as below.  When someone clicks a link inside the UL .list-links I want to capture the value of

```
<span class="asa_portlet_title">Title here</span>
```

in a variable.  I've tried using siblings and closest but it always returns empty.

--

```
<div class="my_portlet" style="display:none;">
    <span class="asa_portlet_title">Title here</span>
</div>

<div class="links">
    <div class="">
        <ul class="list-links">
            <li class="margin-bottom-medium">
                <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a> 
                <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a> 
                <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a> 
                <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

--

```
$('[ul.list-links a').click(function() {
    var _portletTitle = $(this).siblings('.my_portlet').text(); 
});
```

Open to pure javascript method as well.  Basically I have a number of divs on the page containing links, and those divs have another div above it where the title exists

Would anyone be able to put together a small working sample?

Comment: thanks think that was a typo when I was formatting for stackoverflow.

Comment: `.my_portlet` isn't a sibling of the clicked elements so that's why your logic doesn't work. However, how to the `a` elements relate to the single `.my_portlet`? If there is only ever one `.my_portlet` then you don't need DOM traversal at all, just select it directly and get it's text

Comment: On any given page there may be two or three different blocks like the sample above, each block having a different title.  Always in that order but in different places in the dom.  So when a link is clicked, retrieve the .my_portlet title directly above the clicked link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to get the siblings, you are trying to get the sibling of the parent `.links` of `this`.

Also you have to prevent the default action of the a element. You can do that by calling `preventDefault()` on the event object.

```js
$('ul.list-links a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var _portletTitle = $(this).closest('.links').prev('.my_portlet').text();
  console.log(_portletTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_portlet" style="display:none;">
  <span class="asa_portlet_title">Title here</span>
</div>

<div class="links">
  <div class="">
    <ul class="list-links">
      <li class="margin-bottom-medium">
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="my_portlet" style="display:none;">
  <span class="asa_portlet_title">Title here 2</span>
</div>

<div class="links">
  <div class="">
    <ul class="list-links">
      <li class="margin-bottom-medium">
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name 2</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name 2</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name 2</a>
        <a href="linkhere.html" target="_self">Link name 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works just great!  But if I add another identical block so there are two blocks of links and two blocks with titles, it is capturing both when clicked instead of the closest one above it.  I modified your code block to include what I mean.

Comment: You can use `prev()` instead of `sliblings()`. `prev()` will return the first sibling that comes before the current one.  I'll update my answer.